How to add "and references therein" so that it comes out in the bibliography
How to add this line ",and references therein" in the bib file, so that the reference comes out as
... , and references therein,
in the bibliography.
Example include https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.126.132502 (Reference #1).

Does author = {xxx}, title = {yyy}, ..., note = {and references therein} do what you want?

Wouldn't the string "and references therein" be better placed as part of a specific citation call-out'? Placing the string inside a formatted bibliographic entry provides absolutely no context for what "referenced therein" items should be consulted for.

@Marijn: Thank you so much. It works!
